# How can I send R code containing the % symbol to IBM dashDB?

Tags: r, ibm-cloud, node-red, dashdb

I'm trying to send and execute an R script to the IBM dashDB REST endpoint based on the [tutorial](https://github.com/CDSLab/IDUG2015/tree/master/AnomalyApp).

Everything works quite nice but when I use the following code

```
timestamp=as.numeric(strptime(df$TIMESTAMP, \"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.000000\"));
```

The dashDB REST service simply returns:

> An internal error has occurred. Please check the URL and try again.

Using the R web console inside the dashDB service the script runs fine. I've attached the whole script at the end of this message.

Any ideas?

```
library(ibmdbR)
mycon <- idaConnect("BLUDB", "", "")
idaInit(mycon)

df <- as.data.frame(ida.data.frame('"DASH110683"."TEMPERATURE"')[ ,c('NAME', 'TEMPERATURE', 'TIMESTAMP')])

pattern="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.000000"

timestamp=as.numeric(strptime(df$TIMESTAMP, pattern))


maxTimestamp=max(timestamp)
cutOffTimestamp=maxTimestamp - 10
idx = which(timestamp>cutOffTimestamp)
workingSubset=df[idx,]

devideIds=unique(workingSubset$NAME)
scores = 1:length(devideIds)
for (i in 1:length(devideIds)) {
    idx = which(workingSubset$NAME==devideIds[i])
    df=workingSubset[idx,]
    values=as.numeric(df$TEMPERATURE)
    #scores[i]=(sqrt((globalMean- mean(values))^2) +sqrt((globalSD- sd(values))^2))/2
    #scores[i]=abs(globalSD- sd(values))
    scores[i]=sd(values)
}

if (max(scores)>1) {
  devideIdOutlier=devideIds[scores==max(scores)]
} else {
  devideIdOutlier=0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Romeo, the API described in the tutorial is more of a preliminary one. In fact we have just made available the new strategic one that also provides more options. You can now either pass in the R script via a request parameter or you can reference a R script that is stored inside dashDB (e.g. by using the built-in RStudio and saving the script).

https://developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/wp-content/themes/projectnext-clouddata/dashDB/